# .NET JAXB equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net, jaxb

Is there an equivalent library for JAXB in .NET? I am trying to convert an XML I get to a .NET class. I have the XSD, but not sure how to convert the XML received into a concrete Class? I used the [XSD tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx) to generate a class from the schema, but what I want to to convert the XML I receive on the fly to a object that I can work with in code.

I've seen the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765422/jaxb-equivalent-in-c) that deals with this, but my query is - I want the object created to contain the data that I receive in the XML (i.e. the field values must be populated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much better way and more closer to what I was looking for:

```
static public string serializeObject(ProductPriceLines objecteToSerialize)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer mySerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductPriceLines));

        System.IO.MemoryStream t = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        mySerializer.Serialize(t, objecteToSerialize);


        UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
        string strbytes = utf.GetString(t.ToArray());


        return strbytes;
    }
```

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, just curious why this solution is better than Mike Two's. +1 once you respond.

Comment: Your question asks for XML => object. Your answer does it the other way around: object => XML.

Answer (score 10):

You can use xsd.exe to generate the class and then use `XmlSerializer` in your code to populate the class. For example if xsd.exe creates a class called `Foo` you could write:

```
Foo someFoo;
using (var stream = new FileStream("foo.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    someFoo = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```