# Convert XML String to Object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I am receiving XML strings over a socket, and would like to convert these to C# objects.

The messages are of the form:

```
<msg>
   <id>1</id>
   <action>stop</action>
</msg>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have objects these become or are you wanting to dynamically generate the objects?

Comment: look for this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765422/jaxb-equivalent-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765422/jaxb-equivalent-in-c)

Comment: For me this was the best option:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24184283/2647430

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You need to use the `xsd.exe` tool which gets installed with the Windows SDK into a directory something similar to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin
```

And on 64-bit computers:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin
```

And on Windows 10 computers:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin
```

On the first run, you use `xsd.exe` and you convert your sample XML into a XSD file (XML schema file):

```
xsd yourfile.xml
```

This gives you `yourfile.xsd`, which in a second step, you can convert again using `xsd.exe` into a C# class:

```
xsd yourfile.xsd /c
```

This should give you a file `yourfile.cs` which will contain a C# class that you can use to deserialize the XML file you're getting - something like:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(msg));
msg resultingMessage = (msg)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader("yourfile.xml"));
```

Should work pretty well for most cases.

**Update:** the XML serializer will take any stream as its input - either a file or a memory stream will be fine:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(msg));
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
msg resultingMessage = (msg)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

or use a StringReader:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(msg));
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(inputString);
msg resultingMessage = (msg)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. In my case, the XML is coming over a socket, and is a string. How would I de-serialize a string instead of an XML file?

Comment: @Steve: You can open a StringReader and pass the Deserialize method. StringReader derives from TextReader.

Comment: Would you prefer your approach to the one Fahad mentioned using Linq?

Comment: @Steve: yes, I would - deserializing into an object and being able to poke at the object's properties seems a lot easier than doing a lot of wiggling with XML elements, attributes, child nodes etc. Linq-to-XML is great if the XML is irregular and changes all the time, or not known ahead of time.

Comment: This works great! Just one problem that I ran into:
The XML I have:
'<Request_Group attribute1="value">
  <Key name="name" value="value"/>
  <Request_Data>
    <Application attribute11="value">
    </Application>
  </Request_Data>
</Request_Group>'
Code outputted for the "Request_Data" tag (since it doesn't have any attributes):
'[XmlArrayItemAttribute("Application", typeof(REQUEST_GROUPREQUEST_DATAApplication), Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public REQUEST_GROUPREQUEST_DATAApplication[][] REQUEST_DATA { get; set; }'

And the XMLSerializer doesn't seem to like this two dim. array.

Comment: This web site is much easier than the xsd tool IMO: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @nasch: thanks for the hint - that site wasn't around in 2010 when I answered - but good to know there are other (and possibly easier) options out there!

Comment: @marc_s I didn't even notice the age of this question and answer!  Still useful though.

Comment: I used successfully the example with StringReader.

Comment: @nasch Phenomenal link.  Thank you. The xsd tool produced a large output and ended up not working for me.  The Xml2CSharp.com link was more what I was looking for and much tighter/compact.  Thanks again.

Comment: @marc_s, in my case it is stuck on "Writing file", while the XML isn't that big. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: I tried using this xsd tool, it generated wrong classes. The **Paste Special** from the other answer worked and it was much simpler.

Comment: Updating comments for new versions of VS (2019), here is the Windows 10 path for xsd:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools.

Note that there may be a NETFX 4.7 tools as well.

Comment: Another online parser with some configurations https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp. It even writes some code for you.

Answer (score 273):

You have two possibilities.

### Method 1. **XSD** tool

---

Suppose that you have your XML file in this location `C:\path\to\xml\file.xml`

1. Open **Developer Command Prompt**
   You can find it in `Start Menu > Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 > Visual Studio Tools` 
   Or if you have Windows 8 can just start typing **Developer Command Prompt** in *Start screen*
2. Change location to your XML file directory by typing `cd /D "C:\path\to\xml"`
3. Create **XSD file** from your xml file by typing `xsd file.xml`
4. Create **C# classes** by typing `xsd /c file.xsd`

And that's it! You have generated C# classes from xml file in `C:\path\to\xml\file.cs`

### Method 2 - Paste special

---

Required Visual Studio 2012+ with .Net Framework >= 4.5 as project target and 'Windows Communication Foundation' individual component installed

1. Copy content of your XML file to clipboard
2. Add to your solution new, empty class file (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Open that file and in menu click `Edit > Paste special > Paste XML As Classes`
   [image]

And that's it!

### Usage

---

Usage is very simple with this helper class:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // Add reference: System.Web.Extensions
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Helpers
{
    internal static class ParseHelpers
    {
        private static JavaScriptSerializer json;
        private static JavaScriptSerializer JSON { get { return json ?? (json = new JavaScriptSerializer()); } }

        public static Stream ToStream(this string @this)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(@this);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }


        public static T ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(@this.Trim().ToStream(), new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
            return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }

        public static T ParseJSON<T>(this string @this) where T : class
        {
            return JSON.Deserialize<T>(@this.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do now, is:

```cs
    public class JSONRoot
    {
        public catalog catalog { get; set; }
    }
    // ...

    string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file.xml");
    var catalog1 = xml.ParseXML<catalog>();

    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file.json");
    var catalog2 = json.ParseJSON<JSONRoot>();
```

Comment: cheers. re: method 2, you have to target .net 4.5 else the option's not available.

Comment: About the paste special method. Why is it available only in FW4.5? Will I be able to use the generated class in a FW4.0 project, or it won't work?

Comment: Method 2 is ridiculously useful! Thanks for that. I had no idea that existed.

Comment: Kudos for the method 2, works like a charm. Great when trying to simply parse a XML programmatically without having to implement boring classes.

Comment: You should make "Paste Special" as a first method- it's the simplest one. Limitation ".Net Framework >= 4.5" is not important in 2017.

Comment: In my situation I tried `Xml2CSharp` online tool, tried using the `xsd.exe` tool, but both generated wrong classes and was not working for my scenario. That **Paste Special worked perfectly**. I had no idea about it....fantastic tool!!!

Comment: The "Paste XML as classes" requires the WCF workload for Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Paste XML As Classes working, but the class not good for desalinize if the XML contain complex namespaces

Comment: Update answer to have ParseHelpers.ParseXML and ParseHelpers.ParseJSON instead of xml.ParseXML() as xml is just a string.

Answer (score 57):

Try this method to Convert Xml to an object.  It is made for exactly what you are doing:

```
protected T FromXml<T>(String xml)
{
    T returnedXmlClass = default(T);

    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            try
            {
                returnedXmlClass = 
                    (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // String passed is not XML, simply return defaultXmlClass
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return returnedXmlClass ;        
}
```

Call it using this code:

```
YourStrongTypedEntity entity = FromXml<YourStrongTypedEntity>(YourMsgString);
```

Comment: Got this error xmlns=''> was not expected."}, any idea ?

Comment: Problem is, you need to have your class perfectly formed in advance. Maybe a function that outputs a class when given XML? xsd.exe is hit & miss (mostly miss for complex stuff)...

Comment: Oh my god I spent hours dealing with .nets xml serializer, and this worked right out of the gate.

Comment: in case of "was not expected" error use solution above with Edit -> Paste Special instead of manually creating classes

Answer (score 13):

Simply Run Your Visual Studio 2013 as Administration ...
Copy the content of your Xml file..
Go to Visual Studio 2013 > Edit > Paste Special > Paste Xml as C# Classes 
It will create your c# classes according to your Xml file content.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone might find this useful:

```
public static class XmlConvert
{
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(T dataObject)
    {
        if (dataObject == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        try
        {
            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, dataObject);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string xml)
         where T : new()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return new T();
        }
        try
        {
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it using:

```
MyCustomObject myObject = new MyCustomObject();
string xmlString = XmlConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
myObject = XmlConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomObject>(xmlString);
```

Comment: Missing semicolon at XmlConvert.SerializeObject(myObject) :)

Comment: @TimMaes Thanks! Just updated the snippet! (1975 days later) ;-)

Comment: Couldn't wait a day longer :)

Answer (score 10):

You can generate class as described above, or write them manually:

```
[XmlRoot("msg")]
public class Message
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer) to serialize and deserialize.

**Instalation**
You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```

**Serialization:**

```
var serializer = new ConfigurationContainer().Create();
var obj = new Message();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

**Deserialization**

```
var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize<Message>(xml);
```

**This serializer support:**

- Deserialization xml from standard XMLSerializer
- Serialization class, struct, generic class, primitive type, generic list and dictionary, array, enum
- Serialization class with property interface
- Serialization circular reference and reference Id
- Deserialization of old version of xml
- Property encryption
- Custom serializer
- Support XmlElementAttribute and XmlRootAttribute
- POCO - all configurations (migrations, custom serializer...) are outside the class

ExtendedXmlSerializer support **.NET 4.5** or higher and **.NET Core**. You can integrate it with WebApi and AspCore.

Comment: Excellent post!  I updated the code to modernize it according to the documentation https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer

Answer (score 3):

You can use xsd.exe to create schema bound classes in .Net then XmlSerializer to Deserialize the string : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying Damian's great answer,

```
public static T ParseXml<T>(this string value) where T : class
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var textReader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        return (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through all the answers as at this date (2020-07-24), and there has to be a simpler more familiar way to solve this problem, which is the following.

**Two scenarios...** One is if the XML string is **well-formed**, i.e. it begins with something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` or its likes, before encountering the root element, which is `<msg>` in the question. The other is if it is **NOT well-formed**, i.e. just the root element (e.g. `<msg>` in the question) and its child nodes only.

Firstly, just a simple class that contains the properties that match, in case-insensitive names, the child nodes of the root node in the XML. So, from the question, it would be something like...

```
public class TheModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

The following is the rest of the code...

```
// These are the key using statements to add.
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;

bool isWellFormed = false;
string xml =  = @"
<msg>
   <id>1</id>
   <action>stop</action>
</msg>
";

var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
if (isWellFormed)
{
    xmlDocument.RemoveChild(xmlDocument.FirstChild); 
    /* i.e. removing the first node, which is the declaration part. 
    Also, if there are other unwanted parts in the XML, 
    write another similar code to locate the nodes 
    and remove them to only leave the desired root node 
    (and its child nodes).*/
}

var serializedXmlNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(
            xmlDocument, 
            Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
            true
            );
var theDesiredObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheModel>(serializedXmlNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled into it and I have a different answer than, well, everyone else :-)

The usual way (as the commenters above mention) is to generate a class and de-serialize your xml.

But (*warning: shameless self-promotion here*) I just published a nuget package, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dandraka.XmlUtilities/), with which you don't have to. You just go:

```
string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test\books.xml");
var book = Dandraka.XmlUtilities.XmlSlurper.ParseText(xml);
```

That is literally it, nothing else needed. And, most importantly, if your xml changes, your object changes automagically as well.

If you prefer to download the dll directly, the github page is [here](https://github.com/dandraka/XmlUtilities/releases).

Answer (score 1):

> Create a DTO as CustomObject

Use below method to convert XML String to DTO using JAXB

```
private static CustomObject getCustomObject(final String ruleStr) {
    CustomObject customObject = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomObject.class);
        final StringReader reader = new StringReader(ruleStr);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        customObject = (CustomObject) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOGGER.info("getCustomObject parse error: ", e);
    }
    return customObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the xsd of the xml message then you can generate c# classes using the .Net xsd.exe tool.

This .Net classes can then be used to generate the xml.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here you can naturally use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class, for XML DOM-like reading, or the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), fast forward-only reader, to do it "by hand".

Answer (score 0):

Another way with an Advanced xsd to c# classes generation Tools : xsd2code.com. This tool is very handy and powerfull. It has a lot more customisation than the xsd.exe tool from Visual Studio. Xsd2Code++ can be customised to use Lists or Arrays and supports large schemas with a lot of Import statements.

Note of some features,

- Generates business objects from XSD Schema or XML file to flexible C#
  or Visual Basic code.
- Support Framework 2.0 to 4.x
- Support strong typed collection (List, ObservableCollection, MyCustomCollection).
- Support automatic properties.
- Generate XML read and write methods (serialization/deserialization).
- Databinding support (WPF, Xamarin).
- WCF (DataMember attribute).
- XML Encoding support (UTF-8/32, ASCII, Unicode, Custom).
- Camel case / Pascal Case support.
- restriction support ([StringLengthAttribute=true/false], [RegularExpressionAttribute=true/false],
  [RangeAttribute=true/false]).
- Support large and complex XSD file.
- Support of DotNet Core & standard

Answer (score -8):

```
public string Serialize<T>(T settings)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringWriter outStream = new StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(outStream, settings);
    return outStream.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is how to serialize, not how to deserialize.

Comment: You just wrote code here. With no explanation, it's meaningless for many.

Comment: Code doesn't dispose of streams