# How can I parse CCD document from XML file

Tags: c#, .net, ccd, healthvault

I want to build a program to parse CCD document from XML file in C#. 
So I have find and install from nuget HealthVault package, but I don't know if this library is good for my job.
Now my question is, how can I parse CCD document from xml file in Object c#?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XML Schema Definition Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe). Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3187489/3542713) for more information.