# Extract tag values form an XML document C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file from which i have to extract only the attribute values in the tag. The XML kind of looks in this structure

```
<customer> 
    <customerMiddleInitial>W</customerMiddleInitial> 
<name>
      <FirstName>XXXXXXXX</FirstName>
      <LastName> YYYYYYYY</LastName>
</name>
    <customerBirth>1983-01-01</customerBirth> 
    <customerWorkPhone>020 1234567</customerWorkPhone> 
    <customerMobilePhone>0799 1234567</customerMobilePhone> 
    <previousCust>0</previousCust> 
    <timeOnFile>10</timeOnFile> 
    <customerId>CUST123</customerId>
</customer>
```

So, I want to extract all the details between the tags. The expected output should be all the customer details.

How can i implement this in C#?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How to parse XML in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document I think you will find your answer in the link above.

Comment: Without any attempted code which you have troubled with to start, this is simply a duplicate of many older 'how to parse XML in C#' kinda questions...

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument DOC = new XmlDocument();
DOC.Load("LoadYourXMLHere.xml");
XmlNodeList ParentNode = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customer");
foreach (XmlNode AllNodes in ParentNode)
{
 if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customerMiddleInitial"))
{
    customer.Initial = AllNodes["customerMiddleInitial"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("name"))
{
    customer.FirstName= AllNodes["FirstName"].InnerText;
    customer.LastName= AllNodes["LastName"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customerBirth"))
{
    customer.Birthdate= AllNodes["customerBirth"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customerWorkPhone"))
{
    customer.WorkPhone= AllNodes["customerWorkPhone"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customerMobilePhone"))
{
    customer.MobilePhone = AllNodes["customerMobilePhone"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("previousCust"))
{
    customer.PreviousCust= AllNodes["previousCust"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("timeOnFile"))
{
    customer.TimeOnFile= AllNodes["timeOnFile"].InnerText;
}
if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("customerId"))
{
    customer.ID= AllNodes["customerId"].InnerText;
}
}
```

Create a Customer model and execute the above xml parsing in C#.

Sincerely,

Thiyagu Rajendran

**Please mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object)

When you [generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSmc3.png) model just use this code for deserialised xml to object.And after that just use model to work with your data. That is easy and simple

```
    public static T FromXml<T>(String xml)
    {
        T returnedXmlClass = default(T);

        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                try
                {
                    returnedXmlClass =
                            (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // String passed is not XML, simply return defaultXmlClass
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return returnedXmlClass;
    }
```

and using

```
var model = FromXml<customer>(yourXmlString);
```