# How to set values to the variables of an object after Deserializing xml to object?

Tags: c#, deserialization

Facing issues with deserializing XML with multiple tags. Tried deserializing XML with:

```
cars = (Cars[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I want to set values to `cars.colour`, `cars.speed`, etc. values from the XML I am reading.

Comment: See [Convert XML String to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object).

Comment: You should at the very least include a sample of one of your Xml objects as well as some code you have tried.

Comment: @Poosh: Thanks it helped