# Convert XML data to C# class

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

My project is Asp.net Core
I want to convert XML data to C# class,XML data has a node `PersonelInfo` I try to read XML but It's code not working.
How can I solve this code? What is my problem?

```
var xmlGetDetailsUser = new XmlDocument();
xmlGetDetailsUser.LoadXml(await responseMessageGetDetailsUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlGetDetailsUser.InnerXml))
{
    try
    {
        PersonelInfo data = (PersonelInfo)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    { }
}
```

class

```
public class PersonelInfo
{
  public string PersonelCode { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

`xmlGetDetailsUser.InnerXml` has this value  :

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<ArrayOfPersonelInfo xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"sample url .....\">
    <PersonelInfo>
        <PersonelCode>99999</PersonelCode>    
        <Email>test@test.com</Email>        
    </PersonelInfo>
</ArrayOfPersonelInfo>
```

when run my program show this exception in try catch

> There is an error in XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XML String to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object)

Comment: Could the escaped `"` characters be the cause?

Comment: It would be very odd for the *inner* XML to actually contain an `<? xml ... ?>` declaration. Could you post the complete XML?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It is complete XML

Comment: @SebastianHofmann What do you mean about **escaped " characters**?

Comment: @FerasAlSous My question is different it because of my problem XML Data. This XML Data has a node the name of  **PersonelInfo** and I don't know How can I get this node?

Comment: @MohammadDaliri: Look at the XML you've shown - it's got a `\` before each of the `"` characters. Either you've copied that from the debugger (so that's not the *actual* XML) or it's invalid XML.

Comment: It seems that you don't actually write any kind of message inside your catch block. What is the real message you get? (An empty try/catch block in this context is useless, better remove it and let the exception (and the InnerException) show their messages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set namespace for `XmlSerializer` and change type of it to `List<PersonelInfo>`.

Try this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PersonelInfo>), "sample url ....");
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(await responseMessageGetDetailsUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))
            {
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
                {
                    var data = (List<PersonelInfo>)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answers but 
It seems is not a good way for convert XML to C# 
What do you think of improving this code?

```
var xmlGetDetailsUser = new XmlDocument();
xmlGetDetailsUser.LoadXml(await responseMessageGetDetailsUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var result = xmlGetDetailsUser.GetElementsByTagName("PersonelInfo");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonelInfo));
var personelInfo = new PersonelInfo();
personelInfo.PersonelCode = result.Item(0)["PersonelCode"].InnerText;
personelInfo.Email = result.Item(0)["Email"].InnerText;
```

Comment: Could you share us the method defination for `web service`? Will it return an array or an object? Per to xml, it seems to be array instead of object. Try something like`responseMessageGetDetailsUser.Content.ReadAsAsync<PersonelInfo>()` and `responseMessageGetDetailsUser.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<PersonelInfo>>()`

Comment: @TaoZhou My Webservice return array of class