# How can I show xml node into specific textbox c#

Tags: c#, xml

I should show in **specific textboxes**, that I already created, these three values in the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <Val1>a</Val1>
  <Val2>b</Val2>
  <Val3>c</Val3>
</settings>
```

Comment: you have provided almost no information there.  You need to give as much information as possible.  What are you actually stuck with?  Reading xml?  creating a textbox?

Comment: oh ok, sorry. I need to read that xml file and put the "val1", "val2" and "val3" into three different textboxes that I already created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert XML String to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need that when I open the program he put those xml values in the 3 different textboxes.
So textbox 1 will show "a" textbox 2 will show "b" and so on

Comment: This is starting to sound suspiciously like [gimme da codez](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277139/question-asking-for-you-to-write-code). Please edit your question, improve it to prove me wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but I managed to solve, I posted the answer with the solution, thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way, but I don't know if it is the best:

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(variabili.direcotry_db + "document.xml");

            XmlNodeList CList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Val1");
            for (int i = 0; i < CList.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = CList[i].InnerText.ToString();
            }
            XmlNodeList CList2 = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Val2");
            for (int i = 0; i < CList2.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox2.Text = CList2[i].InnerText.ToString();
            }
            XmlNodeList CList3 = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Val3");
            for (int i = 0; i < CList3.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox3.Text = CList3[i].InnerText.ToString();
            }
```