# How to get value from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Given the following XML file:

```
<root>
   <country>
       <name></name>
       <locationOU>null</location>
   </country>
   <country>
       <name>Sweden</name>
       <locationOU>Some Value</locationOU>
   </country>
   <country>
       <name>Lithuania</name>
       <locationOU>Some Value</locationOU>
   </country>
   <country>
       <name>Belgium</name>
       <locationOU>Some Value</locationOU>
   </country>
</root>
```

How do I get the value of `locationOU` based on name value eg. `name = Sweden`?

Comment: It seems you would need to parse the file into objects.  (Similar to deserializing a json). Would this post solve your issue?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) via [`XPathSelectElement(XNode, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelement?view=net-6.0#System_Xml_XPath_Extensions_XPathSelectElement_System_Xml_Linq_XNode_System_String_).

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

// Read XML file
XDocument root = XDocument.Load(/* Your XML file path */);

// Read XML from string
// XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XElement result = root.XPathSelectElement("/root/country[name='Sweden']");
        
string locationOU = result.Element("locationOU").Value;
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dCajLM)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It seems like a get an error on the `XDocument root = XDocument.Parse("Locations.xml");` that says: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"

Comment: No, you use `XDocument.Parse()` by providing the XML string. If you want read XML from file. use [`XDocument.Load("Your file path")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Ah! That removed the error, thank you :) However `locationOU` is null. I can see when I debug, that it has the correct country and that the value for <locationOU></locationOU> is there

Comment: Never mind! I see that I had a typo in my XML :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I like using xml linq with a dictionary :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("country")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("name"), y => (string)y.Element("locationOU"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string sweedenLocation = dict["Sweden"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that the `Value` are all null. If I look at Sweden for instance, the `key` is Sweden and the `Value` is null

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XML_TEXT);
XElement rootElement = doc.XPathSelectElement("root");
var countries = rootElement?.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.Equals("country"));
var yourCountry = countries.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName.Equals("locationOU") && d.Value == "Sweden");
```

Comment: I get an error on `e =>`: "A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath with above answers @Yong Shun

Or You can use DataSet as bellow:

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
ds.readXml(filename);
DataTable dt=ds.Tables[0];
string name="Sweden";
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Select(String.Format("name='{0}'",name))
{
    string locationOU=dr["locationOU"].toString();
}
```