# accessing information within c# script in java

Tags: java, c#, process, scripting

I created a new exe with a C# script which I then execute inside of a Java program. The exe will pull a string from a process that is running and print it to the screen. I was wondering how to access that string in the exe through Java, if there is a way.

Comment: might be best to just have java also pull from the process that is running.  Aside from that, could always try some c# / java interop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689/java-and-c-sharp-interoperability

Answer (score 3):

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String txt = null;
while ((txt = br.readLine()) != null) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I was using the wrong buffer and stream! Much appreciated. Will accept the answer when I can :D